# Why should we place interfaces with classes that use them rather than those that implement them?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, package

I was going through an article by Robert C. Martin and at one place he gave a example like this:

The first image shows that there's a cyclic dependency between the two packages. To remove this dependency a new interface is added in the second image. B implements the interface and Y uses it. And Martin makes the following point:

> Interfaces are very often included in the package that uses them, rather than in
>   the package that implements them.

My question is, why should we arrange interfaces this way? What is the reasoning behind packaging interfaces this way? According to Common Closure Principle classes that change together should stay together. Is an interface closer to its implementer or its user, in terms of change???

[image]

Comment: But interfaces can be used and can be implemented in different modules. In our company we store them in a separate module that is being references by all of them, that ways they are a module per se. This is important for us because we have lots, and I mean LOTS of interfaces, and it easier to mantain everything like this... even more so if you have company rules on who can commit to some path in the repository. And not everybody can make changes to interfaces...

Comment: But then if the interface changes you'll have a hell lot of change spreading across so many modules isn't it???

Comment: FYI -- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html. This puts the situation into a clearer perspective I think. It's the need to bypass the dependency structure that may cause a situation like this. But what about general scenarios???

Comment: The point is more about who and when can change interfaces... changing interfaces often means bad design. Interfaces are changes very ocasionally and always by people who know what they are doing and why. When this happens yes, there will be some work to adjust all modules that use the inreface (of course if something has changed, not been added, since addition does not break anything). You cannot rely on all programmers in a multinationaly comapny in 10 sites along the world to behave as experts, so some process requirements must have priority over desing patterns :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, the user is no closer to the interface than the implementor. In terms of change both will need to change when the interface changes.

However, why would the interface change?

The user calls to an interface so it can be independent of whatever implementor is available. Therefore the definition of the interface is dictated by the needs of the user.

As the user dictates the definition of the interface, there is no point changing the interface if the user doesn't need it. An implementor requiring a change to the interface to accommodate the implementation should send up red flags. Why does it need more or different information from the user? What use is that to the user?

Also, the implementor "merely" depends on the interface in as much as it needs to provide implementations for each of the methods in the interface. But it is free to provide empty stubs, in essence delivering a NOP to its clients.

So, the user's needs drive changes to the interface and changes to the interface drive changes to the implementor(s). As such the user is functionally much closer to the interface than the implementor. Which makes a good case to declare the interface with the user and not the implementor.

Answer (score 2):

It should first be said that there's no one way to skin a cat.

This particular methodology is useful when splitting up a project up between multiple project teams or creating a system with decoupled sub-systems. The interface serves as a "contract" between two sub-systems. By the placing the interface on "their turf", the consuming party has a better guarantee that the interface will remain unchanged, unless the implementing party contacts the consuming party to request such a change.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we use interfaces as a protocol between a server and a client so that the client knows what services are available but there's a side effect for this approach , the client will be dependent to the server and therefore if something changed in server side that affects the given interface the client should change too.
So there's this principle among the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles , invented by Robert C. Martin, and that's "[Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)" or "[DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)" , that as it name implies says we should invert the dependency between client and server in order to avoid client changes in future.In this approach client says what it's going to need via an interface and server should implement it to serve what it needs, therefore no changes in server side make us to change the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of **resolving cyclic dependencies** between components `AB` and `XY`. None can be compiled without the other. `AB` is referencing `XY` and `XY` is referencing `AB`.

Robert C. Martin is appying the **InversinOfControl** pattern to resolve this

Now `XY` is referencing `ABInterface`. `ABInterface` does not need to know `XY` at all.

Your are right, this violates cohesion (you called it Common Closure Principle)

It also contradicts the KeepItSimple principle. The simplest solution would have only one monolitic component `ABXY` that is much harder to maintain.

Comment: Well the question really is why he wants to keep the interface with the class that uses it. We don't want to go into alternate designs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to implement an interface until there's something that needs it. YAGNI.

Comment: Hmm. Let's assume that RCM is developing a pattern or let's say that the interface "is" needed. I'm not concerned with the pattern here. I'm more concerned by the statement he made about the locality of interfaces.